# How to loop through keys of JavaScript object

Tags: javascript, loops, key

I have an object that looks like this:

```
var myObj = {
    name:"Bacon",
    fat:20,
    carb:40
}
```

Is there a way to do a loop on the keys of the object, to then get its value?

Comment: This is not json, this is javascript object.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can traverse through javascript following way:

```
for (var key in p) {
  if (p.hasOwnProperty(key)) {
    alert(key + " -> " + p[key]);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

This should work.

```
for (var key in myObj) {
   if (myObj.hasOwnProperty(key)) {
       var obj = myObj[key];
        for (var prop in obj) {
          if(obj.hasOwnProperty(prop)){
            alert(prop + " = " + obj[prop]);
          }
       }
    }
}
```